# Problem with Interpolation in Density Plot

Tags: plotting, data

I have this [DATA](https://pastebin.com/k0tWUDBD) points:

```
{{0., 0., 0.117237}, {0.125, 0.0721688, 0.0185109}, {0.125, 0.216506, 
  0.08128}, {0.25, 0., 0.08128}, {0.25, 0.288675, 0.0215464}, {0.25, 
  0.433013, 0.0978551}, {0.375, 0.0721688, 0.0215464}, {0.375, 
  0.216506, 0.0796793}, {0.375, 0.505181, 0.0215464}, {0.375, 
  0.649519, 0.08128}, {0.5, 0., 0.0978551}, {0.5, 0.433013, 
  0.0796793}, {0.5, 0.721688, 0.0185109}, {0.5, 0.866025, 
  0.117237}, {0.625, 0.0721688, 0.0215464}, {0.625, 0.216506, 
  0.0796793}, {0.625, 0.505181, 0.0215464}, {0.625, 0.649519, 
  0.08128}, {0.75, 0., 0.08128}, {0.75, 0.288675, 0.0215464}, {0.75, 
  0.433013, 0.0978551}, {0.875, 0.0721688, 0.0185109}, {0.875, 
  0.216506, 0.08128}, {1., 0., 0.117237}}
```

that I want to make a density plot. Using high orders of Interpolation does not give an accurated result. I'm trying to do something like this

[image]

I've tried to use ListDensityPlot and change the parameters InterpolationOrder -> 1 and MaxPlotPoints -> 100. The result is as follows

[image]

As you may notice the result is not exactly the same, but I wish reach the same aspects, with all black around the triangle.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/k0tWUDBD"];
```

Construct a [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object using the first two columns of `data` as values and the last column as weights:

```
wd = WeightedData[data[[All, ;; 2]], data[[All, -1]]];
```

Use `wd` with [`SmoothDensityHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html):

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[wd, .05, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  AspectRatio -> All, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Play with second argument (*bandwidth*) to get the desired picture.

Comment: I had some trouble to plot the whole image. What you suggest?

Comment: Because of -> General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation. Some points are not appearing

Comment: I Think SetAccuracy[data[[All , ;;2]],2] solved the problem