# How to set a max value to barlegend in plots in general

Tags: plotting

I had a problem with interpolation in Density plot that was solved [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261746/problem-with-interpolation-in-density-plot/261750#261750)

Now, I would like to set the value of the barlegend in the following DATA in a specific value.

```
DATA={{0., 0., 0.117237}, {0.125, 0.0721688, 0.0185109}, {0.125, 0.216506, 
  0.08128}, {0.25, 0., 0.08128}, {0.25, 0.288675, 0.0215464}, {0.25, 
  0.433013, 0.0978551}, {0.375, 0.0721688, 0.0215464}, {0.375, 
  0.216506, 0.0796793}, {0.375, 0.505181, 0.0215464}, {0.375, 
  0.649519, 0.08128}, {0.5, 0., 0.0978551}, {0.5, 0.433013, 
  0.0796793}, {0.5, 0.721688, 0.0185109}, {0.5, 0.866025, 
  0.117237}, {0.625, 0.0721688, 0.0215464}, {0.625, 0.216506, 
  0.0796793}, {0.625, 0.505181, 0.0215464}, {0.625, 0.649519, 
  0.08128}, {0.75, 0., 0.08128}, {0.75, 0.288675, 0.0215464}, {0.75, 
  0.433013, 0.0978551}, {0.875, 0.0721688, 0.0185109}, {0.875, 
  0.216506, 0.08128}, {1., 0., 0.117237}}
```

The max value in DATA z-axis is 0.117237, in which, the brightest spot in smoothhistogram correspond to this value. Lets suppose that I want to set the max value in BarLegend and for the brightest spot, for example, 0.20. How could I do this? Should I insert an imaginary set like, {x,y,0.20}, where x and y will set way far from the x,y points in DATA?

As mentinioned before, I'm using this to get the plot

```
wd = WeightedData[SetAccuracy[DATA[[All, ;; 2]],2], DATA[[All, -1]]];

SmoothDensityHistogram[wd, .05, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  AspectRatio -> All, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> False]
```

Edit1: I want to compare two data sets [DATA1](https://pastebin.com/q4GB4usk) and [DATA2](https://pastebin.com/YgGeWbLF), in which, each one has its respective maximum value, so I would like to set a BarLegend corresponding to maximum value in DATA1 (around 20) and see the corresponding brighter spot in DATA2 (around 0.07) less bright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Legended[
 SmoothDensityHistogram[wd, .05,
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  AspectRatio -> All,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> False],
 BarLegend[{"GrayTones", {0, 0.2}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I made an edit with other data sets because doing like your suggestion I cant see the difference in bright between a density plot with max value in 20, and a density plot with max value 0.07 setting this BarLegend with {0, 20}.

Comment: I think we need to set this max value in the SmoothDensityHistogram instead...So I'll move it to other Question, thanks for your help here.

Comment: Unless you turn off the `ColorFunctionScaling`, the arguments supplied to a color function are scaled to lie between 0 and 1. The min value maps to `0` and the max value maps to `1`. The `BarLegend` above maps this range `{0, 1}` to `{0, 0.2}`. You will see more contrast if you change the `ColorFunction`, e,g., `Legended[ SmoothDensityHistogram[wd, .05, ColorFunction -> (cf = "Rainbow"), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, AspectRatio -> All, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False], BarLegend[{cf, {0, 0.2}}]]`

Comment: Ok! There is any way to make this colorfunctionscaling correspond to a max value? With that, we could see darker points in DATA2 in the new post that I've made https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264539/how-to-set-a-max-value-in-smoothdensityhistogram

Comment: Also, I can put a string on the barlegend?

Comment: Add to the `BarLegend` the option `LegendLabel -> "whatever"`